# update or ignore multiple documents in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in which all of my documents have at least these 2 fields, say name and age (where name is unique so I set up a unique index on it). Now if I try to update a document with a duplicate name, it will give an error and stop the program. I don't want this behavior, but I need something like mysql's update or ignore, so that mongoDB should not update the document with duplicate name and continue with the next documents.

My collection

```
{ "_id" :1, "name" : "dev", "age" : 14 }
{ "_id" :2, "name" : "devraj", "age" : 20 }
```

The command I've tried:

`db.test.update({name:'dev'},{$set:{name:"devraj"}})`

Gave me this error:

```
"errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.test index: name_1 dup key: { : \"devraj\" }"
```

Comment: how is this related to php and/or java ?

Comment: have you defined a [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-index-and-missing-field) by `name`?

Comment: yes i am define name as unique index